# Yii: How to validate a form field? It can be null, but can not empty

Tags: php, validation, yii

Yii:  How to validate a form field? It can be null, but can not empty.

For example, I have a Book Model. When I do a form submitting, some of the fields can be null(not set), But It should not empty.

How to check it?

Comment: What exactly is the control or controls you use to get user input for this field? How is the user supposed to tell you "my input is null" vs "my input is the empty string"?

Comment: Can you give the meaning of "null" and "empty"? Because in my opinion null is same with empty

Comment: empty means empty string. such as "".
"" is an empty string. But it is not null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, just not use that field in "required" validator, and use for this field any other, like "numeric" or some another validator. 
It will do a trick for you.

Comment: if you use the "required" rules it means that the attribute can not be null or empty

Comment: @aslingga sure, and i wrote "not use"